# C3Js graph x-Axis is displaying outside of graph

Tags: c3

The X-Axis labels are moving to the left outside of the graph when I am zooming in and/or slide the graphs content to right or left.

On this image you can see that the label (05.08) is outside on the left.

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this ugly display error ?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in C3 that you should raise with its developer.

Answer (score 2):

Kinda late answer.

I've solved the same issue by redefining c3 core functions *getXAxisClipX* and *getXAxisClipWidth* to the following

```
c3.chart.internal.fn.getXAxisClipX = function() {
  var $$ = this;
  return $$.getAxisClipX(!$$.config.axis_rotated) + Math.max(30, $$.margin.left);
};

c3.chart.internal.fn.getXAxisClipWidth = function() {
  var $$ = this;
  var chartMargin = $$.margin;
  return $$.getAxisClipWidth(!$$.config.axis_rotated) -
    Math.max(30, chartMargin.left) -
    Math.max(30, chartMargin.right);
};
```

Here is the example https://jsfiddle.net/vhpzma97/

Comment: Hi @Eskandar, I'm using c3chart angular directive, I dont know how to access this core functionality and do it. do u have any idea?